# Mapping blank in a string to a number

Tags: python

I am trying to create a numeric multiclass target variable based on a multiclass string variable, but I am getting errors. Here in my code I am using

```
mapping_target = {'Went to another company': 1, 'Fired': 2, 'Retired' : 3, '':0}
df_employee1.EmploymentEnd2 = [mapping_target[item] for item in df_employee1.EmploymentEnd2]
```

Here is the error I am getting.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-185-72c0cd51fdd0> in <module>
      1 mapping_target = {'Went to another company': 1, 'Fired': 2, 'Retired' : 3, '':0}
----> 2 df_employee1.EmploymentEnd2 = [mapping_target[item] for item in df_employee1.EmploymentEnd2]

<ipython-input-185-72c0cd51fdd0> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 mapping_target = {'Went to another company': 1, 'Fired': 2, 'Retired' : 3, '':0}
----> 2 df_employee1.EmploymentEnd2 = [mapping_target[item] for item in df_employee1.EmploymentEnd2]

KeyError: nan
```

How can I access blank values in the mapping above so that I can assign it value 0?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first use `fillna` to replace all nan values with the empty string like so:

```
df_employee1.EmploymentEnd2 = df_employee1.EmploymentEnd2.fill_na("")
```

And then you can use `map` instead of looping (which imo looks cleaner) like:

```
df_employee1.EmploymentEnd2 = df_employee1.EmploymentEnd2.map(mapping_target)
```

Which should accomplish what you need

Comment: Perfect solution. Thank you.